# Ошибки отправки запроса на сервер через fetch()

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

На странице формы подключен скрипт js, который отправляет запрос на сервер при клике пользователя на одной из двух кнопок. Затем сервер возвращает ответ и браузер выводит сообщение с полученными данными.

js:

```
let element = document.querySelector('.button');

element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    fetch("http://my_site/test", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({"key": event.target.value})
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => alert(data));
});
```

серверный скрипт Laravel:

```
Route::post('/test', function (Request $request) {

    $data = $request->input('key');
    return json_encode($data);

});
```

В результате при клике по любой из кнопок в консоль выводятся следующие сообщения об ошибках:

```
POST http://my_site/test 419 (unknown status)

POST http://my_site/test 419 (unknown status)

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```

Как я понял первые две ошибки говорят о проблеме с csrf-токеном. Попытался вылечить это добавив
в разметку тег `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`, но ошибка не ушла.

Две последние, как я прочитал говорят о том, что скрипт js отправляет не json, а html. Здесь я вообще не нашел, что можно предпринять.

Как устранить эти ошибки?
Почему они задублированы?
Спасибо!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ошибки возникают из-за того, что сервер возвращает **ошибку 419**, которая указывает на проблему с **CSRF-токеном**. Для решения этой проблемы необходимо добавить **CSRF-токен** в заголовок запроса. Для этого можно использовать следующий код:

```
let element = document.querySelector('.button');
let csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    fetch("http://my_site/test", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({"key": event.target.value})
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => alert(data));
});
```

Чтобы скрипт отправлял данные в формате **JSON**, необходимо убедиться, что сервер возвращает данные в формате **JSON**. В данном случае сервер возвращает **HTML**, что вызывает ошибку. Чтобы решить эту проблему, необходимо изменить серверный скрипт **Laravel**, чтобы он возвращал данные в формате **JSON**. Для этого можно использовать следующий код:

```
Route::post('/test', function (Request $request) {

    $data = $request->input('key');
    return response()->json($data);

});
```

**Если эти изменения не помогут, то возможно, что проблема заключается в другом месте кода.**

Comment: Клобайт, все заработало. Спасибо! Еще парочка вопросов))  1. Когда сервер присылает ответ, он получается задублирован. Т.е. нажав одну кнопку я в консоли получаю два раза $data. Может из-за того, что у меня две кнопки слушают событие?  2. При загрузке страницы консоль выдает такую ошибку  -  Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/open_server/OSPanel/domains/pet-project/resources/assets/css/home.css. Таблица стилей подключена в шаблоне Laravel  так <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ resource_path('assets/css/home.css') }}">
Компиляция  через @vite - @vite(['resources/css/app.css']).

Comment: спасибо за помощь!!!  Я здесь недавно и не полностью ознакомился с правилами этого ресурса. Нажал галочку напротив вашего ответа - чтоб отметить ответ как принятый + стрелочку вверх - чтоб отметить как полезный. Надеюсь все верно) Еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

> Отметьте, пожалуйста, мой предыдущий ответ как правильный.)

1. Если сервер присылает ответ дважды, возможно, что проблема действительно связана с тем, что у вас две кнопки, слушающие одно и то же событие. Попробуйте добавить условие, чтобы запрос отправлялся только при клике на нужную кнопку:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
let csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

elements.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if (event.target.value === 'value') {
            fetch("http://my_site/test", {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({"key": event.target.value})
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => alert(data));
        }
    });
});
```

1. Ошибка `Not allowed to load local resource` возникает, когда вы пытаетесь загрузить файлы из локального диска напрямую в браузере. Для исправления этой ошибки необходимо запустить сервер на локальном хосте и загружать файлы через него. Вам необходимо изменить путь к файлу таким образом, чтобы он загружался через сервер. Например, если вы используете сервер `Laravel`, то можно изменить путь следующим образом:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/home.css') }}">
```

Если вы используете сборщик `Vite`, то можно использовать следующий код:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```

В этом случае, файл `CSS` будет загружаться через сервер, который запущен на локальном хосте.
`<insert-here/>`